# MKAnnotationView: How to know when it's put into reuse queue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, mkannotationview

In my custom annotation views, I have UIImageViews refer to UIImages, so I'd like to release these images when the annotation views are put into reuse queue, so the question is, is there any callback for that? Or any other workaround to prevent it from in memory all the time (e.g: clear them when receiving memory warning)?

I know there is prepareForReuse() for custom classes to prepare right before it's being reused, but I'd like to release those images and other resources it's holding as soon as the annotation view turns into an inactive state if possible.

Answer (score 0):

In `didDeselectAnnotationView:` delegate method, remove child views from AnnotationView

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didDeselectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    for (id childView in view.subviews)
    {
        [childView removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Comment: It tells the delegate the annotation view is turned into unselected state, not unused state, so I can't release any resources at this time.